# Dynamically generate 3D objects

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, vrml, helix-3d-toolkit

I have to to generate a 3D object dynamically, depending on several input parameters. Some elements inside the object should be clickable.

The following conditions must apply:
 - Viewer is [Helix](https://github.com/helix-toolkit)
 - The generator must be callable from C#
 - Generation must be "fast".
 - Import of vrml/3ds files (templates/graphic library)
 - The generator must support boolean operations (for example subtract sphere from cube)
 - The generator must support things like chamfers or fillets on edges

Optional conditions: 
 - Support of animations in 3D objects (for example animate size change of object)

How would you realize this (no solution, only approaches)? Some requirements like Helix can be ignored if there are better options available.

Comment: *How would you realize this?* is waaay to broad. Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried several ways. But i didn´t want to restrict you. One possibility would be an CAD Core like OpenCascade with C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add my two cents on your sketched project plan.

- C# calling is the least problematic issue, if nothing else remains, your code can operate as a controller to a middleware entity, that performs the dirty part of the job and that finalizes the VRML-neutral output for any post-processing.
- You plan ought to be either viewer-agnostic ( VRML97/VRML2.0 can warrant that )
  or viewer-specific, which will deflect your solution from portability
- After some 30 years in CAD/CAM, there are many approaches to re-use some Boolean modeller
- Importing VRML into modeller is "built-in"
- Chamfers / fillets are "classical" Boolean modeller <kbd>sub</kbd> operations

To get some inspiration, check Andy's AC3D approach, with **great & cool** API & Tcl/Tk interfacing options ( if I may judge after some integration work done this way ) - all your features are supported / achievable there since some mid-90's last century ( The time is passing so, so, so fast )

[image: Boolean operations on _both_ 3D & 2D objects]

And many "new" or "handy" nice-to-have-s were added during the last 20 years

[image][image][image]